# Space between bullets and floated image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I was experiencing an issue in IE11, where if a bulleted list was next to a floated images, the bullets were staying to the left, whereas the text was wrapping around (as expected) the the right.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</li>
    <li>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</li>
    <li>'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</li>
    <li>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</li>
    <li>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I managed to solve the issue by pulling the bullets inside the `li` but now, I'd like to align the bullets with the `p` tags (aka respect the image's margin).  This is what I have so far:

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-indent: -1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</li>
    <li>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</li>
    <li>'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</li>
    <li>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</li>
    <li>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
    <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</li>
    <li>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</li>
    <li>'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</li>
    <li>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</li>
    <li>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
  </ul><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work? (adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<li>`)

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  text-indent: -1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placebear.com/300/300" />
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</li>
    <li>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</li>
    <li>'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</li>
    <li>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</li>
    <li>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
    <li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</li>
    <li>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</li>
    <li>'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</li>
    <li>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</li>
    <li>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
  </ul><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: yep! that does it!  Will accept your answer once the timer allows :)

Comment: Cool, glad to help, friend :)